# How to use OR in search query for Github API

Tags: python, github-api

I'm searching files in repos in Github, using the Github API.

And I know how to use AND in my search query, it's like this: `q=term1+term2+term3` but what this does is search for all of the words in a file. Here, all terms must be in the file, for it to be included in the search.

But what if I want to see if **any** of the words are there?

I have tried this: `q=term1 OR term2 OR term3` but this did not work. I also tried to use the Python `or` in the string, but of course that did not work either.

```
def find_phrases(urls):
    # Search terms to search files in all repos
    terms1 = 'seven day'or'seven days'or'7-day'or'7-days'or'7 day'or'7 days'
    terms2 = 'free trial OR trial key OR trial keys OR try OR try experience OR trial experience'
    terms3 = 'trial subscription OR http:\/\/azure.microsoft.com\/try\/cognitive-services OR https:\/\/azure.microsoft.com\/try\/cognitive-services'

    directory = urls[0].replace('https://github.com/', 'repo:')

    query = f'{terms1}+in:file+{directory}'
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}')
```

These are some of the documents I'm using in the Github API documentation, but I have not found anything on how to use OR.

https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search

https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax

https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#constructing-a-search-query