# How do I use the Github Search API to look for repositories, using multiple queries?

Tags: github, github-api

As per the official documentation - "*For example, if you want to search for popular Tetris repositories written in assembly code, your query might look like this:

```
q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc
```

This query searches for repositories with the word tetris in the name, the description, or the README. The results are limited to repositories where the primary language is assembly. The results are sorted by stars in descending order, so that the most popular repositories appear first in the search results.*"

However, I'd like to use more than one keyword to avoid false positives. For instance I want to count repositories that make use of the TensorFlow framework for meta-learning. However, I don't see there is any code example for this. Could someone please help with that?

Here is what I did using the THUNDER CLIENT extension in VSCode, but I am not sure if it's correct -

```
 https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=Tensorflow, meta-learning+language:python
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566682/how-to-use-or-in-search-query-for-github-api) question, where the poster says to use "+". However, I don't see any official documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/):

```bash
gh api --method=GET "search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc"
```